# When I delete cell from tableview cells that are not deleted are duplicated SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView which I created with firebase data.

Here is my load func :

```
  var reservationList = [UserModal]()

 private func loadposts() {
        reservationList = []
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        Database.database().reference().child("BookReservations").observe(.value) { snapshot in
         
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                guard let dict = child.value as? [String:Any] else {
                    print("Error")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    return
                }
                let name = dict["name"] as! String
                let date = dict["date"] as? String ?? "nil"
                let book = dict["bookName"] as? String ?? "nil"
                let FullDate = dict["fullDate"] as? String ?? "nil"
                let phoneNumber = dict["phoneNumber"] as? String ?? "nil"
                
                let reservations = UserModal(name: name, dateAndTime: date, choosenBook: bookName  , phoneNumber: phoneNumber, tamRandevu: fullDate)
                self.reservationList.append(reservations)
                print(self.reservationList)
                
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
extension ReservationListViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reservationList.count
    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reservationCell", for: indexPath) as! reservationCell
        cell.bookNameLabel.text = reservationList[indexPath.row].choosenBook
        cell.nameLabel.text = reservationList[indexPath.row].userName
        cell.dateAndTimeLabel.text = reservationList[indexPath.row].fullDate
        cell.phoneButton.setTitle(reservationList[indexPath.row].phoneNumber, for: .normal)
        
        return cell
    }
```

I can get value and show on tableView. But when I try to delete cell :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if editingStyle == .delete {
        
        print("Deleted")
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        let reservationTime = reservationList[indexPath.row].fullDate ?? "nil"
            print(reservationTime)
        
            if reservationTime != "nil" {
                
                let stationsRef = database.child("BookReservations") 
               
                print(reservationList.count)

                

                  print("Before deleting Count of reservation list : \(reservationList.count)")
            
            reservationList.forEach { (UserModal) in
                print(UserModal.name)
            }
            stationsRef.child(reservationTime).setValue(nil)
          
            reservationList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            
          
            
           
         
            print("After deleting Count of reservation list : \(reservationList.count)")
          
            reservationList.forEach { (UserModal) in
                print(UserModal.name)
            }
                
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
               
               
            }else{
              
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                print("no reservation found.")
            }
        
      }
    }
```

I can succesfully delete data from firebase real time database. But when I delete data , If there is more than one data in the tableView, the non-deleted data will repeat itself.
I try to check my array count it seems good when delete count is decreasing.. I try tableview reload, begin updates and and updates but nothing works. Only works when I refresh tableview with refresh method. This is my print outputs :

Before deleting Count of reservation list : 2
Optional("yakalaaa")
Optional("xyzzz")
After deleting Count of reservation list : 1
Optional("yakalaaa")

this is my tableView which I load with firebase data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElzP6.png)

I delete second cell :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxQyS.png)

and this is the problem :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNG7.png)

any suggestions ?

Comment: no I checked. I can delete selected item  stationsRef.child(reservationTime).setValue(nil)

Comment: The problem isn't in this code. Is there anywhere else that you append to `reservationList`? What output do you get in the console?

Comment: No the only place I do append is loadpost function.This is my output when  delete method works.  Before deleting Count of reservation list : 2 Optional("yakalaaa") Optional("xyzzz") After deleting Count of reservation list : 1 Optional("yakalaaa")

Comment: Then show your tableview methods (number of rows and cellForRow).

Comment: Also, put a debug print or set a breakpoint in your observer closure to tell you when it is being called. I don't use Firestore, but I don't think you are using it correctly.

Comment: It works when I refresh the tableview. Also I update question with number of rows method

Comment: What do you mean "refresh" the tableview?  Do you mean reload all of the data?  Did you check when your observer is firing. I think it is firing when you delete the item so you get a duplicate value.

Comment: Oh yes its firing when I delete you're right

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: Move `reservationList = []` to inside the closure

Comment: I tried it too, it doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

the problem is with these lines:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
reservationList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

just use instead

```
reservationList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.reloadData()
```